# Capybara tests failed on codeship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rspec feature test which uses capybara to test the front-end. The test runs ok on my local development environment but it fails on codeship. 
The error is from capybara that says cannot find css element. So why does this happen? Thanks!

Comment: check what the full html of the page is that capybara is looking at when it can't find the css element. That will usually give you some hints.

Comment: How can I check the full html page on codeship?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I haven't used codeship before.

Comment: @Kingsley you can use `save_and_open` to check the html page.